# C function that accepts default arguments

Tags: c, function, default-arguments

Im trying to code a C function that has a optional argument, and if that argument isn't "used", then it has a default value.

```
int DumpData(int a, int b, int c=0)
{

if(c != 0)
{
          //stuff
}
    //banana
}

/* Function Call */

DumpData(1, 2);
```

Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Comment: In a word: no. C is not C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this in C.  The best you can do is to have separate functions:

```
int DumpData(int a, int b)
{
    return DumpDataABC(a, b, 0);
}

int DumpDataABC(int a, int b, int c)
{
    ...
}
```

Or, use C++ instead of C.

Comment: That seems understandable but when i tried to implement in my code i couldnt figure out how to. So if user doesnt input `c`, what function do i call ?

Comment: @xRed: If there's no `c`, you call the two-parameter function `DumpData`; if there is a `c`, you call the three-parameter function (which I've called `DumpDataABC` here; you can probably find a better name, but without more context I wasn't able to use the best name).  The two function names must be different, since C doesn't have function overloading.

Answer (score 2):

In C, this can be achieved with macros. The implementation of such a thing is a bit tricky, so you'd better use an existing toolbox to do so. I have collected such things in [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr). With that you could define something like

```
#define DumpData(...) P99_CALL_DEFARG(DumpData, 3, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DumpData_defarg_2() 0
```

The first line  declares a macro that is supposed to receive 3 parameters. The second line substitutes a `0` in place of parameter 2, if that one is omitted (parameter count starts with 0).

Such a macro can in fact be named the same as your function, all of this is then transparent to the user at the calling side.

Comment: Does this compile correctly under `-pedantic`? That is what is tripping me up right now for what I was trying to do.

Comment: You need a compiler that supports C99 for that, in fact P99 is intended to be completely C99 complying. For gcc e.g that means that you'd have to use the `-std=c99` option on the command line and not the misleadingly named `-ansi` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of C11 features, such as variadic macros, designated initializers and compound literals you can accomplish something similar, I know this example is trivial but this approach could be useful for functions with a lot of arguments in which more than one requires a default value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct {
  int a, b, c;
} dumpdata_args;

#define DumpData(...) DumpData_Impl((dumpdata_args){.c = 0, __VA_ARGS__})

int DumpData_Impl(dumpdata_args args)
{
  if(args.c != 0)
  {
          //stuff
  }
      //banana  
}

/* Function Call */

DumpData(.a=1,.b=2);
DumpData(.a=1,.b=2,.c=3);
```